# Receiving error: _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame3.!treeview"

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am writing a simple program for a local business that will allow its users to easily keep track of their job service tickets.  At one point, I had the program working with no errors.  However, being that I am very new to programming and had typed a lot of messy code, I went back and decided to clean some of it up, as well as added better functionality.  In doing so, I caused an error to occur, and I can't seem to fix it.

I have tried multiple ways to solve this issue, but all I have been able to determine is that if I remove a small block of code, it will essentially run as it should.

Here are the two definitions:

```
def gui_elements_remove(self, elements):
     for element in elements:
        element.destroy()

def Load(self):

    self.gui_elements_remove(self.gui_elements) 
    
    var = self.FirstTree.focus()
    treevar = self.FirstTree.item(var)
    JobDF = pd.DataFrame(treevar, index = [0])
    self.JobID = JobDF.iloc[0]['values']

    cursor1 = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from 'Service Tickets' WHERE JobID = ?", (self.JobID))
    SP = cursor1.fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(SP, columns = [
                                    'ServiceTicketsID',
                                    'JobID',
                                    'Ticket Number',
                                    'Reason for Visit',
                                    'Warranty/VPO',
                                    'Date Ticket Received',
                                    'Date of Service',
                                    'Service Person'
                                    ])
 


    columns =   [
                'ServiceTicketsID',
                'Ticket Number',
                'Reason for Visit',
                'Warranty/VPO',
                'Date Ticket Received',
                'Date of Service',
                'Service Person'
                ]


    LoadFrame = Frame(self.root)
    LoadFrame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True, padx = 50)
    scroll = Scrollbar(LoadFrame, orient = VERTICAL)
    SecondTree = ttk.Treeview(LoadFrame, yscrollcommand = scroll.set, columns = columns)
    SecondTree['show'] = 'headings'
    SecondTree.heading('#1', text = 'ServiceTicketsID')
    SecondTree.heading('#2', text = 'Ticket Number')
    SecondTree.heading('#3', text = 'Reason for Visit')
    SecondTree.heading('#4', text = 'Warranty/VPO')
    SecondTree.heading('#5', text = 'Date Ticket Received')
    SecondTree.heading('#6', text = 'Date of Service')
    SecondTree.heading('#7', text = 'Service Person')
    SecondTree.column('#1', width = 0, stretch = NO)
    SecondTree.column('#2', width = 75, stretch = YES, anchor = "n")
    SecondTree.column('#3', width = 75, stretch = YES, anchor = "n")
    SecondTree.column('#4', width = 75, stretch = YES, anchor = "n")
    SecondTree.column('#5', width = 100, stretch = YES, anchor = "n")
    SecondTree.column('#6', width = 100, stretch = YES, anchor = "n")  
    SecondTree.column('#7', stretch = YES, anchor = "n")   
    scroll.config(command = SecondTree.yview)
    scroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
    SecondTree.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = TRUE)
    Maintree = df   [[
                    'ServiceTicketsID',
                    'Ticket Number',
                    'Reason for Visit',
                    'Warranty/VPO',
                    'Date Ticket Received',
                    'Date of Service',
                    'Service Person'
                    ]]
    Maintree_rows = Maintree.to_numpy().tolist()
    for row in Maintree_rows:
        SecondTree.insert("", 0, values = row)

    for col in columns:
        SecondTree.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: \
                    self.Treeview_sort_column(SecondTree, _col, False))

    b1 = Button(LoadFrame, text = "Add")
    b2 = Button(LoadFrame, text = "Update")
    b3 = Button(LoadFrame, text = "Cancel")
    b1.configure(command = lambda: self.Load_Add())
    b2.configure(command = lambda: self.Load_Update())
    #b3.configure(command = lambda: self.Cancel_Button(LoadFile, self.MainWindow, self.root))
    b1.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 50)
    b2.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 50)
    b3.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 50)
```

There is more code but what I've provided should be more than enough, hopefully.  The first method is called to clear out the frame from the previous method being run.  The remainder is supposed to take the user's selection from the previous TreeView.  However, upon running this code, I am given the error

```
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame3.!treeview"
```

If I comment out this block of code:

```
        var = self.FirstTree.focus()
    treevar = self.FirstTree.item(var)
    JobDF = pd.DataFrame(treevar, index = [0])
    self.JobID = JobDF.iloc[0]['values']

    cursor1 = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from 'Service Tickets' WHERE JobID = ?", (self.JobID))
    SP = cursor1.fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(SP, columns = [
                                    'ServiceTicketsID',
                                    'JobID',
                                    'Ticket Number',
                                    'Reason for Visit',
                                    'Warranty/VPO',
                                    'Date Ticket Received',
                                    'Date of Service',
                                    'Service Person'
                                    ])
```

As well as the remaining code affiliated with it, the program runs correctly.  The frame is cleared out and the new TreeView is brought in, as well as its headers.

As I said, I am brand new to programming and as such am new to using StackOverflow.  With that said, I apologize if I've not provided enough information, posted incorrectly, etc.  I also apologize in advance for any sloppiness you may find in the code lol.

I appreciate all input.

Comment: The error either means you've created more than one instance of `Tk`, or that you're trying to access a treeview widget which has been destroyed.

Comment: Bryan, one of the widgets being destroyed at the beginning of this code contains the treeview that I am trying to take data from.  
I have tried moving gui_elements_remove() to happen after the variable is taken from the previous table, but it doesn't work.  
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
JobDF = pd.DataFrame(treevar, index = [0])
```

and

```
cursor1 = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from 'Service Tickets' WHERE JobID = ?", (self.JobID))
```

were the culprits.

It should have been

```
JobDF = pd.DataFrame(treevar) #removed the index argument
```

and

```
cursor1 = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from 'Service Tickets' WHERE JobID = ?", (self.JobID,))  #added a comma (self.JobID,))
```